# UI wont show images

Tags: python, tkinter

I need help I've recieved this code from my friend as we were co-editing but now the gallery button wont show any images the app we were trying to make  an app which will be used as a networking/online gallery for less known artists to help them come up. I've done my best I even tried going off of the ide and focusing more on the folders to see if i can fix it there but can anyone help. Here is the code:

```
def show_gallery_window(self):
    gallery_window = tk.Toplevel(self.root)
    gallery_window.title("Gallery")
    gallery_window.geometry("800x600")  # Set window size to 800x600
    gallery_window.configure(bg="lightblue")  # Set background color

    # Create a frame to display images and ratings
    frame = tk.Frame(gallery_window, bg="lightblue")
    frame.pack(fill=tk.BOTH, expand=True)

    # List of image file paths (replace with your image file paths)
    image_paths = ["image1.png", "image2.png", "image3.png", "image4.png", "image5.png"]

    for index, image_path in enumerate(image_paths):
        # Load the image
        image = tk.PhotoImage(file=image_path)

        # Display the image in the gallery
        label = tk.Label(frame, image=image)
        label.grid(row=index // 2, column=index % 2, padx=10, pady=10)

        # Display the rating below the image (you can replace this with actual ratings)
        rating_label = tk.Label(frame, text="Rating: 5", font=("Arial", 12))
        rating_label.grid(row=index // 2 + 1, column=index % 2, padx=10, pady=5)

        # Add a "Rate" button (you can replace this with actual rating functionality)
        rate_button = tk.Button(frame, text="Rate", command=lambda i=index: self.rate_drawing(i))
        rate_button.grid(row=index // 2 + 2, column=index % 2, padx=10, pady=5)
```

Please not that I've tried reading all I could and couldnt find a solution online or anywhere my problem might be related to files but i tried fixing that too so help would be appreciated

Comment: I think your code has [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16424091/why-does-tkinter-image-not-show-up-if-created-in-a-function) problem. Right now, you posted too much code for anyone to read through and understand. Try making an [mre]

Comment: Right.  The problem is well-described in the duplicate.  In what can legitimately be called a bug, `tk.Label` does not grab a reference to the image you pass in, so when your function exits, the `image` is deleted.